# how to set false/true for this.$refs.focus(); in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to change focus with `$refs`,
 but I see this error .

> 1. [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"
> 2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    openTest() {
      if (this.$refs.FocusOrderDelivery.focus() == true) { // err <== 
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    retFlase() {
      this.$refs.FocusOrderDelivery.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>


  <button
    @click="retFlase"
    >
    barcode
    {{openTest}}
  </button>
  <input
    class="nothing"
    ref="FocusOrderDelivery"
    href="javascript:void(0)"
  />
</template>
```

---

this is live err  this.$refs.focus()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUk0B.jpg)

Comment: Do you just want the focus to start on the input field? Or only when you have clicked the button?

Comment: @Mm.Mirzaei.dev Could be a timing issue . From the docs : Because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! $refs is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding. Try remove `openTest()` property and try again.

Comment: The error also states `Error in render` so it's probably that

Comment: @Mm.Mirzaei.dev Please take a look at my answer and accept if it helped you! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error states `Error in render` - This is most-likely a timing issue. I found this piece in the official docs : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#ref

```
An important note about the ref registration timing:
because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function,
you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!
$refs is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use
it in templates for data-binding.
```

I guess the same thing applies to computed properties. Try to remove `openTest` computed property and see if it helps !

**Focus/ Unfocus Input**

Since `focus` is a method to set focus on a DOM Element, you can not simply set true or false for this state. Use `focus()` to focus and `blur()` to unfocus. Doing this via a button click should be totally fine. ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp )

**Keep track of focus state with a data prop**

Since you can't get the focus state of an element by its $ref directly, you are probably better of the outsource the focus state into another data prop and update it whenever the element gets focused/unfocused (blur). Vue hast 2 event you can use for this : `v-on:focus` and `v-on:blur` .

```js
<template>
<div>
  <input v-on:focus="setFocus(true)" v-on:blur="setFocus(false)" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isFocus : false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setFocus(bool) {
         this.isFocus = bool;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Also interesting**

Just stumpled over this method to find the currently focused element in the DOM : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement , might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 0):

For your actual purpose, you can leave much of all the focus check out of the picture.

EDIT: There's not any "good" way of getting to know if a field is actually focused from the only using the `$refs`, therefore i've made the approach below.

You can make better use of the `@focus` and `@blur`, and then only use the `$refs` to actually focus the field:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="retFlase">
      barcode
      {{ hasFocus }}
    </button>
    <input
      class="nothing"
      @focus="hasFocus = true"
      @blur="hasFocus = false"
      ref="FocusOrderDelivery"
      href="javascript:void(0)"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      hasFocus: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    retFlase() {
      this.$refs.FocusOrderDelivery.focus();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bhaskara-hxuc3